# Google maps v2 white screen only see zoom. It used to work

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm getting a white screen on my google maps app - zoom buttons are showing. I'm revisiting code I wrote last year that worked fine so it should all be ok. I'm testing on a gingerbread 2.3.3 phone.

1. I have google maps v2 enabled
2. I have a matching api key in my manifest: AIzaSyCKzmEns8anNV3QLLBRIw3f88Y7TmsXXXX
3. I have the correct hash/domain in use for my debug:

   ```
   D6:35:00:83:CD:F6:2F:69:44:FB:D2:9E:AE:DE:F0:1B:27:01:1D:FF;com.example.androidac_session8a
   ```
4. In my project I have google-play-services-lib linked
5. I have the google APIs SDK downloaded and set as the target
6. In my code I check that a googlemap object is returned, which it is and inside logcat there are no errors generated
7. My manifest is ok as far as I know:

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="9"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
       <activity
           android:name="com.example.androidac_session8a.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>

       <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" 
           android:value="AIzaSyCKzmEns8anNV3QLLBRIw3f88Y7TmsXXXX"/>
       </application>
   ```
8. My layout is inside a tabbed view but here is the xml:

   ```
   <fragment
   android:id="@+id/worldmap"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   ```
9. Here is the code to initialise the map. I have additional code to update it to show satellite and draw stuff but I've removed that.

   ```
   private void initialiseMap() {
       //get the fragment and call getMap on it which returns a GoogleMap
       if (googleMap == null) {
             googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                   R.id.worldmap)).getMap();

           // check if map is created successfully or not
           if (googleMap == null) {
               Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(),
                       "Unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                       .show();
           }
       }       
   }
   ```

Comment: re=generate the api key and test again

Comment: is there any chance you use different machine from what you used before when it was working? On different machines debug.keystore is different, so map_key generated on one machine won't work on another (unless you use the same debug.keystore on both machines)

Answer (score 2):

debug keystore may expire within 1 year. Though there is no fix time limit. As you told that your code is one year old, so i think your key has expired. So better create new apikey. And usually white screen problem is occurred for wrong api key.

Open your terminal and execute the following command to generate SHA-1 fingerprint.

On Windows

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

On Linux or Mac OS`

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

and using this SHA-1 fingerprint create new api key

Answer (score 0):

It's so bad I could cry ;)

I went on holiday and turned off packet data.

I have wifi on but at work my wifi hotspot is flaky at best yet wifi stays on but does nothing.

I enabled packet data and it worked.

3 hours I've spent reinstalling eclipse, google play library, regenerating keys....

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I doubt you would have the same problem but anyways give it a try . I set the default LatLng to zoom to at the start of the map to (0,0) and a very high zoom level . so I was seeing a desert at a high zoom level which seemed like map didn't load at all.

So try zooming out of the map or try explicitly setting the latLng and zoom level at the start of the map.